# PDO Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I searched already, but nothing, that I found helped me with my code:

```
function getData($con, $table) {
    $stmt = $con->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function getDataByUsername($con, $table, $username) {
    $stmt = $con->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE `username` = "' .     $username . '";');
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

The getData function works just fine, but when I use getDataByUsername I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in     /home/moe/www/status/inc/functions.php on line 12
```

Line 12 is this one:

```
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Thanks for your help, moro

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. The error message is telling you exactly what's going on: `$stmt` is not an object. Since that is the return value of `query()`, you should consult the documentation to see when the return value is not an object. It turns out that when the query causes an error the return value is `false`. This means that your query is wrong, which at a glance happens because you are using double instead of single quotes to wrap `$username`.

Comment: In the future, please try to follow such steps or googling the error message before asking a question. Additionally, you should learn about how to use prepared statements and bound parameters in order to make your code [resistant to malicious hacking attempts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) (your current code looks vulnerable).

Answer (score 1):

Since it is [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo), why not bind variables?

```
function getDataByUsername($con, $table, $username) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE `username` = ?');
    $stmt->execute( array($username) );
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$con->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE `username` = "' .     $username . '";');
```

To

```
$con->query("SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE `username` = `" .     $username . `";");
```

The extra character is called the "tick", which can be found above the TAB key.

Better:

```
$con->query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE `username` = {$username};");
```

Didn't test that last, but you can use variables inline in this way.

Of course mind the remarks made by @Jon.

Comment: No, that's wrong. If `$username` is the string `username` then your query will be `WHERE username = username`, which doesn't do anything.

Comment: hmm .. interesting. I'll keep that in mind. In the meantime I tested that I don't need the ticks on that last query. Does, in your experience, prevent that problem you mention?

Comment: You only need ticks if the table/column name is a reserved word or if you want to use special characters.

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting fact.

Answer (score -2):

the problem is : the character ;
delete it, it's the solution

like :

```
$stmt = $con->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE `username` = "' .     $username . '"');
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with your code. :/